# Mobile video is being played inspite of autoplay is set to false

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari, html5-video

I am trying to set the `autoplay` to `false`, so that a video play will be initiated only on request. However, on some platforms the video is still being played automatically on page load.

The snippet is:

```
<video style="pointer-events: auto; top: 43px; left: 144px; width: 311px; height: 233px; position: absolute; overflow: visible; z-index: 4;" mute="0" controls="" autoplay="false"><source src="http://fcache.veoh.com/file/f/l1890828.mp4?e=1351456564&ri=6000&rs=100&h=652b686b21bf91bb57c13996ef6be62a" type="video/mp4"></video>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/breakphreak/N5Dbq/

The URL to try is here: http://jsfiddle.net/breakphreak/N5Dbq/show

For example on iPad2 (iOS 6), the video is played, while on the *new* iPad (or should I say iPad3, iOS 5) the video is played only when "play" button is pressed?

What am I doing wrong please? How can I require the video to be played only upon an explicit user request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Removing autoplay="false"

http://jsfiddle.net/N5Dbq/4/

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
```